# Validating a date in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetime

I am trying to valid user input in a textbox which will only takes dates or an empty value (hence the textbox vs a date time picker). Here are the conditions:

- Only a date value ("dd-mm-yyyy" or "dd-mm-yy)
- Must contain only slashes or numbers
- The date has to be on the day it is being typed in

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub tbApp1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tbApp1.TextChanged
        If Not Me.tbApp1.Text = String.Empty Then
            If Not DateTime.TryParseExact(tbApp1.Text.Trim, formats, New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtTemp) Then
                If Not tbApp1.Text.Trim = DateTime.Today.Date Then
                    ErrorProvider1.SetError(tbApp1, "This is not a valid date; Enter in this format ('M/d/yyyy' or 'M/d/yy')")
                End If
            Else
                ErrorProvider1.Clear()
            End If
        ElseIf Me.tbApp1.Text.Trim = "" Then
            ErrorProvider1.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub
```

## Masked Textbox use

```
'Private Sub mtbApp1_TypeValidationCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TypeValidationEventArgs) Handles mtbApp1.TypeValidationCompleted
        If Not Me.mtbApp1.Text = String.Empty Then
            If (Not e.IsValidInput) Then
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(mtbApp1, "The data you supplied must be a valid date in the format mm/dd/yyyy.")
            Else
                ' Now that the type has passed basic type validation, enforce more specific type rules. 
                Dim UserDate As DateTime = CDate(e.ReturnValue)
                If (UserDate = DateTime.Now) Then
                    ErrorProvider1.SetError(mtbApp1, "The data you supplied must be today's date")
                    e.Cancel = True
                End If
            End If
            ErrorProvider1.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub'
```

I noticed for a date like 03/18/2014 when it loaded back into the masked textbox it converts to 31/82/014. How could i fix this? The query pulls back the field as

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Date,101) AS Date
```

I set it in vb as :

```
 Dim Approval1 As Date = Nothing
```

and then

```
 If Not IsDBNull(((WorklistsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Approval1")))) Then
                Approval1 = ((WorklistsDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Approval1")))
            End If
```

and then loaded into the masked textbox as:

```
If Approval1 <> Nothing Then
                Me.mtbApp1.Text = Approval1
            End If
```

Comment: Looks like a job for MaskedTextBox. :)

Comment: I was thinking about about it as a possible solution. I will try that and see what I come up with...

Comment: Why not use the built-in .net validation events?  [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Validated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: See edit above. How would I check that a date is not entered

Comment: When I pull a date back from the database such as 03/18/2014 it loads into the masked textbox as 31/82/014/ How could I handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could also simplify your validation with

```
If IsDate(tbApp1.Text) Then 
    'valid date now just check if date falled within permitted range
    Dim CompDate As Date = CDate(tbApp1.Text)
    Dim MidDate As Date = *enter your min date here*
    Dim MaxDate As Date = *enter your max date here*
    If CompDate >= MinDate AndAlso CompDate <= MaxDate Then
        'Date is within permitted range
        ......
    Else
        'Date outside range
        'Display error
    End If
Else
   'text in tbApp1 is not a date
   'Display Error
End If
```